# Code not getting to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

so I have this javascript class with a function _setUpEvents(), but it seems like the code doesn't even get there, the console log inside doesn't output anything in the console. Any idea on how to fix it? (I'm a noob btw.)

**code**:

```
  class Switcher {

     constructor() {

    if (document.getElementById("employee-dropdown"))
        this.init();
    }

    init() {

        this._setUpEvents();
    }

    _setUpEvents() {

        console.log("got here.");
        const select = document.getElementById("employee-dropdown");
        let winloc = window.location.pathname;

        select.addEventListener("change", function() {

            window.location = this.value;

        });

        let location_types = [
            "/employees/",
            "/allocations/list/employee/",
            "/advance-payment/",
            "/deductions/",
            "/voucher/",
            "/allocations/create/",
            "/pay-packets/",
            "/timesheets/creator/",
        ];

        for ( var i = 0; i < select.length; i++ ) {

            var option = select.options[i];

            for ( var loc in location_types ) {

                if ( (winloc.indexOf(loc) !== -1) && (option.value.indexOf(loc) !== -1) ) {

                  option.selected = "selected";
                  break;

                }
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Any errors in your [dev console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Be sure that you have an element with the id `employee-dropdown` cause that is the only thing that would make it not work.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you are creating a new instance of the 'Switcher' class elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I use `new Switcher();`, I forgot to add that at the end of this file I also have `export default Switcher;`.
The element employee-dropdown is there, I made sure.

Comment: Was just about to ask about the missing bracket - I assume that was not the problem?

Comment: @KenSyme Nope, all brackets are fine.

Comment: As others have said need a bit more context about how this is used - [my simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/r8ako5fo/) using it works so the class is probably fine - what does the html of the page look like and where do you call `new Switcher()`